# Selenium how to store value not reference C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I've got a little problem with my test. I need to store a value from a drop down item. The drop down work's like that:

1. I'm typing a product number
2. Drop down displays the product with info about current price and available amount
3. I get the amount
4. I add product to cart
5. Now I need the amount for tests

This is the code for getting the value:

```
public string getProductDetail(string Xpath)
    {
        return this.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath)).GetAttribute("innerText");
    }
```

This is the string where I want to save the amount:

```
string amount = this.interfaceActionHandler.getProductDetail(
            XPath.productAvailableAmount
            );
```

This is the code where I want to use the amount:

```
input.SendKeys(amount + "1");
```

The problem is, when I get to the input.SendKeys part I get:

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

After I choose the product I want to add to cart the drop down closes and the product list becomes invisible.
It's made with Kendo Framwork, and the site code can not be changed.

Any suggestions how to get it workin?

Comment: Are you using Specflow?

Comment: It's hard to tell because you haven't provided very much code but it looks like you are calling .SendKeys() which triggers the fetch of the amount but by that time it's no longer visible. Fetch the amount while the dropdown is open. If you add more of the scenario code, we may be able to see the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the value while the drop down is expanded and it's visible. But when I want to use that value to change the amount in cart the drop down closes and the only thing that the test sees is the reference not the value.